# How can I override a resource in a Terraform module?

Tags: terraform

I've got a Terraform module like this:

```
module "helloworld" {
  source = "../service"
}
```

and `../service` contains:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cpu_max" {
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "2"
  ... etc
}
```

How do you override the `service` variables `comparison_operator` and `evaluation_periods` in your module?

E.g. to set `cpu_max` to `4` is it as simple as `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm .cpu_max.evaluation_periods = 4` in your module?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use a `variable` with a default value.

```
variable "evaluation_periods" {
    default = 4
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cpu_max" {
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "${var.evaluation_periods}"
}
```

And in your module

```
module "helloworld" {
  source = "../service"
  evaluation_periods = 2
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend this approach !!

Answer (score 3):

you'll have to define variables in your module. Your module would be:

```
variable "eval_period" {default = 2} # this becomes the input parameter of the module

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cpu_max" {
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "${var.eval_period}"
  ... etc
}
```

and you'd use it like:

```
module "helloworld" {
  source = "../service"
  eval_period = 4
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thought I could use the v0.11 "override" feature.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers using variables:

If you want to override the whole resource or just do a merge of configuration values, you can also use the overriding behaviour from Terraform:

- [Version 0.12 and later (as of 19/10/2020).](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html)
- [Version 0.11 and earlier.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/override.html)

Using this feature you could have a file named `service_override.tf` with the content:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cpu_max" {
   comparison_operator = "LessThanThreshold"
   evaluation_periods  = "4"
   ... etc
}
```

Comment: I believe this approach is only for resources that are defined elsewhere in your project; that is, it doesn't work if the resource is defined in a module. I've been trying to figure out a good way to override something in a 3rd party module and it looks like I'm just going to have to fork it.

Comment: I can confirm @MattWebster comment. If you have a .tf file that uses the module block, whatever resources the module block introduces can not be acted on by the override feature.